# How to perform a query against timestamps?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, date

I want to be able to find entries created a certain number of days before or after today. I have some models that include timestamps. There is about 70k of those records in the database so running .all.each takes a significantly long time.

I was hoping to do something like

```
Model.find_by_updated_at(Date.today - 1)
```

It seems though that updated_at actually returns class Time, not Date; and because it's precise down to minutes and seconds, I can't do something like

```
Model.find_by_updated_at(Time.now + 10000) # ten thousand seconds
```

because my requests only want to find models changed on a particular day.

Is there a way to do this using find?

I think I could write my own SQL query instead of using find but I'm not sure how to construct it to exclude searching through hh:mm:ss and only look at dates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query is looking for models created at a very specific time. What you might want is something that returns things created after a particular time:

```
Model.where('updated_at>=?', Date.today - 1)
```

Or perhaps in a range:

```
Model.where('updated_at BETWEEN ? AND ?', Date.today - 1, Date.today)
```

There's several ways to do this. You may find it's faster to create an indexable `DATE` column if you do this often enough.

The alternative is to do it dynamically like:

```
Model.where('DATE(updated_at)=?', Date.today - 1)
```

It's almost always possible to express what you want in ActiveRecord terms without having to resort to writing your own query. In fact, it's probably best if you avoid that unless you have a very good reason so your code is more maintainable.

Remember that "day" is a rather fuzzy concept at best. If you store your data in UTC time, which you should, you will need to make adjustments to the beginning and end times or you will be using UTC 00:00:00 as the beginning of your days. This may not match up with your expectations.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a method on your model that looks like this:

```
def self.updated_on_date(date)
   where('updated_at BETWEEN ? AND ?', date.beginning_of_day, date.end_of_day)
end
```

Then you can call it like this

```
Model.updated_on_date(Date.today-1)
```